# Взять из картинки превью

Tags: android-sdk, java, android

Есть папка с картинками. Каким образом можна из картинки  (форматов jpg, png) взять превью и вернуть их в Drawable?

Comment: Превью вернуть в Drawable?

Comment: Ну да. Мне нужно что бы эту превьюшку вернуло в Drawable.
Так же как я делаю с иконками папок, аудио и тд.
`сontext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dir);` только для File с картинкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этого нельзя сделать, потому что ресурсы в Drawable должны быть определенны на этапе сборки, когда генерируется класс R. Превью можно сделать например при первом обращении с помощью сжатия исходной картинки, как это сделать можно посмотреть тут. http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/catshop/bitmap.php#base64

Answer (score 1):

**Выражайтесь корректнее, что вы хотите.**

Drawable - это не только тип ресурсов, но и тип данных. Если вы хотите преобразовать изображение, не хранящееся в ресурсах, к этому типу, воспользуйтесь одним из следующих статических методов этого класса:

```
Drawable.createFromPath(String path_to_file);
```

или же

```
Drawable.createFromStream (InputStream is, String srcName);
```

Как обычно, подробнее читайте на **[оффсайте](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html)** Android SDK.